# Keycloak Device Tokens Support?

Tags: keycloak

I read this question that was asked since 2014-2016. Right now is still not support?

https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-February/004821.html

http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2014-January/001116.html

From link above. Here's my thoughts on device mgmt, both UI and protocol:

Scenario:

An iOS device as a "Brokerage App" installed.  The app needs to do REST 
invocations to be able to trade stocks, etc.  Devices must be registered 
in order to obtain permission.  Flow would look like this:

- User installs app on iPad.
- User hits login button on app.
- User is redirected to browser with a Keycloak server URL
- User enters in credentials
- User is redirected to "Device Registration" page.  Keycloak asks user 
  if it authorizes access to the device.
- Keycloak registers the device under the user and generates a device token
- User is redirected back to iPad ap
- iPad app gets auth code from redirect URL
- iPad makes REST request to obtain auth token *AND* a device token.
- iPad app stores the device token.

Thanks